# Creating tabs for a Signing Group results in duplicates

Tags: docusignapi

I'm having an issue where my request to create tabs is resulting in duplicate fields stacked ontop of each other. I've tested this within my application, and in Postman.

**Note** -  The recipient is a signing group. But whether I have just one or multiple users within the group, the fields get duplicated.

Post Endpoint: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{Account}/envelopes/{envelope}/recipients/5/tabs

**My request:**

```
  {
  "checkboxTabs": [
    {
      "documentId": "640",
      "name": "RE-WORK",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "tabLabel": "Send to Salesperson",
      "xPosition": "163",
      "yPosition": "743"
    }
  ],
  "initialHereTabs": [
    {
      "documentId": "640",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "535",
      "yPosition": "705"
    }
  ],
  "textTabs": [
    {
      "anchorString": "TOTAL SALE PRICE:",
      "anchorUnits": "pixels",
      "anchorXOffset": "-5",
      "anchorYOffset": "80",
      "documentId": "637",
      "locked": "true",
      "pageNumber": "1"
    },
    {
      "anchorString": "TOTAL SALE PRICE:",
      "anchorUnits": "pixels",
      "anchorXOffset": "-5",
      "anchorYOffset": "80",
      "documentId": "640",
      "locked": "true",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "value": "Send back to Salesperson"
    }
  ],
  "dateSignedTabs": [
    {
      "anchorString": "ACCEPTED BY DEALER",
      "anchorUnits": "pixels",
      "anchorXOffset": "100",
      "anchorYOffset": "35",
      "documentId": "636",
      "pageNumber": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

**The Response:**

```
{
    "initialHereTabs": [
        {
            "scaleValue": "0",
            "optional": "false",
            "documentId": "640",
            "recipientId": "5",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "535",
            "yPosition": "705",
            "width": "0",
            "height": "0",
            "tabId": "da69d19b-6f70-4d44-8fb3-a4953d60cc8b",
            "tabType": "initialhere"
        },
        {
            "scaleValue": "0",
            "optional": "false",
            "documentId": "640",
            "recipientId": "5",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "535",
            "yPosition": "705",
            "width": "0",
            "height": "0",
            "tabId": "3b1ad0cc-bc82-49ca-b334-acafec6bc48f",
            "tabType": "initialhere"
        }
    ],
    "dateSignedTabs": [
        {
            "value": "",
            "font": "arial",
            "bold": "false",
            "italic": "false",
            "underline": "false",
            "fontColor": "black",
            "fontSize": "size7",
            "localePolicy": {},
            "documentId": "636",
            "recipientId": "5",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "436",
            "yPosition": "730",
            "width": "0",
            "height": "0",
            "anchorString": "ACCEPTED BY DEALER",
            "anchorXOffset": "100",
            "anchorYOffset": "35",
            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
            "anchorCaseSensitive": "false",
            "anchorMatchWholeWord": "true",
            "anchorHorizontalAlignment": "left",
            "anchorTabProcessorVersion": "v1_3",
            "tabId": "adad3065-95d5-43be-ad0f-022d44585f87",
            "tabType": "datesigned"
        }
    ],
    "textTabs": [
        {
            "isPaymentAmount": "false",
            "shared": "false",
            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
            "requireAll": "false",
            "value": "",
            "required": "true",
            "locked": "true",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "false",
            "maxLength": "0",
            "font": "arial",
            "bold": "false",
            "italic": "false",
            "underline": "false",
            "fontColor": "black",
            "fontSize": "size7",
            "localePolicy": {},
            "documentId": "640",
            "recipientId": "5",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "34",
            "yPosition": "744",
            "width": "0",
            "height": "0",
            "anchorString": "TOTAL SALE PRICE:",
            "anchorXOffset": "-5",
            "anchorYOffset": "80",
            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
            "anchorCaseSensitive": "false",
            "anchorMatchWholeWord": "true",
            "anchorHorizontalAlignment": "left",
            "anchorTabProcessorVersion": "v1_3",
            "tabId": "5e3503a6-52da-44c9-80dc-9d3c046d7e54",
            "tabType": "text"
        },
        {
            "isPaymentAmount": "false",
            "shared": "false",
            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
            "requireAll": "false",
            "value": "Send back to Salesperson",
            "required": "true",
            "locked": "true",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "false",
            "maxLength": "0",
            "font": "arial",
            "bold": "false",
            "italic": "false",
            "underline": "false",
            "fontColor": "black",
            "fontSize": "size7",
            "localePolicy": {},
            "documentId": "640",
            "recipientId": "5",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "34",
            "yPosition": "744",
            "width": "0",
            "height": "0",
            "anchorString": "TOTAL SALE PRICE:",
            "anchorXOffset": "-5",
            "anchorYOffset": "80",
            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
            "anchorCaseSensitive": "false",
            "anchorMatchWholeWord": "true",
            "anchorHorizontalAlignment": "left",
            "anchorTabProcessorVersion": "v1_3",
            "tabId": "c019a6f7-4ec2-45e6-8822-4337fc449868",
            "tabType": "text"
        },
        {
            "isPaymentAmount": "false",
            "shared": "false",
            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
            "requireAll": "false",
            "value": "",
            "required": "true",
            "locked": "true",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "false",
            "maxLength": "0",
            "font": "arial",
            "bold": "false",
            "italic": "false",
            "underline": "false",
            "fontColor": "black",
            "fontSize": "size7",
            "localePolicy": {},
            "documentId": "637",
            "recipientId": "5",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "34",
            "yPosition": "744",
            "width": "0",
            "height": "0",
            "anchorString": "TOTAL SALE PRICE:",
            "anchorXOffset": "-5",
            "anchorYOffset": "80",
            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
            "anchorCaseSensitive": "false",
            "anchorMatchWholeWord": "true",
            "anchorHorizontalAlignment": "left",
            "anchorTabProcessorVersion": "v1_3",
            "tabId": "a0c3ecb5-903b-45e7-8092-007bc9af71f7",
            "tabType": "text"
        },
        {
            "isPaymentAmount": "false",
            "shared": "false",
            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
            "requireAll": "false",
            "value": "Send back to Salesperson",
            "required": "true",
            "locked": "true",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "false",
            "maxLength": "0",
            "font": "arial",
            "bold": "false",
            "italic": "false",
            "underline": "false",
            "fontColor": "black",
            "fontSize": "size7",
            "localePolicy": {},
            "documentId": "637",
            "recipientId": "5",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "34",
            "yPosition": "744",
            "width": "0",
            "height": "0",
            "anchorString": "TOTAL SALE PRICE:",
            "anchorXOffset": "-5",
            "anchorYOffset": "80",
            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
            "anchorCaseSensitive": "false",
            "anchorMatchWholeWord": "true",
            "anchorHorizontalAlignment": "left",
            "anchorTabProcessorVersion": "v1_3",
            "tabId": "7f90abbe-ab5a-405f-bd0b-8500306d8307",
            "tabType": "text"
        }
    ],
    "checkboxTabs": [
        {
            "name": "RE-WORK",
            "tabLabel": "Send to Salesperson",
            "selected": "false",
            "shared": "false",
            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
            "font": "arial",
            "bold": "false",
            "italic": "false",
            "underline": "false",
            "fontColor": "black",
            "fontSize": "size7",
            "required": "true",
            "locked": "false",
            "documentId": "640",
            "recipientId": "5",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "163",
            "yPosition": "743",
            "width": "0",
            "height": "0",
            "tabId": "cad7380a-177c-49d1-bed7-08de88beb2c8",
            "tabType": "checkbox"
        },
        {
            "name": "RE-WORK",
            "tabLabel": "Send to Salesperson",
            "selected": "false",
            "shared": "false",
            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
            "font": "arial",
            "bold": "false",
            "italic": "false",
            "underline": "false",
            "fontColor": "black",
            "fontSize": "size7",
            "required": "true",
            "locked": "false",
            "documentId": "640",
            "recipientId": "5",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "163",
            "yPosition": "743",
            "width": "0",
            "height": "0",
            "tabId": "473c8c1c-e6bf-4f8f-8fea-047248fa7633",
            "tabType": "checkbox"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Anchor Tag Population Scope is "Envelope", so the DocumentId parameter will be ignored. This is definitely the reason why the "TOTAL SALE PRICE" tags are being duplicated. To change this setting, you'll need to open a case with [DocuSign Support](http://support.docusign.com/) requesting "Anchor Tag Population Scope" be set to "Document" for your account. If this is a Sandbox account, please clearly state as such and include your Demo account number.

For the other instances, are there tags placed on anywhere on the envelope prior to your POST call? Either from a template, or from the initial envelope creation call?

Comment: There was definitely tags during the initial envelope creation. By the time it gets to this duplication issue, the envelope would have already been signed by multiple people. This scenario is when the checkbox for "RE-WORK" has been selected - this invokes a series of API calls that adds new signers, appends a new document, and then runs the create tabs request that's above.